# Write a Scheme function (sumList)

Tags: racket

Write a Scheme function (sumList) that returns the sum of all the numbers in a list which should be passed as a parameter. The list can have numbers, non-numeric symbols, and other lists. Your function should select all the number in the sublists and add them to the total. You can assume that the total is 0 if the list is empty. Example Usage:

> (sumList  '((1 2 3)  5 a (10) ())
>   21

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please attempt the problem yourself then feel free to ask specific questions you have about your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (sumList lst)
  (cond   
    ([empty? lst] 
        0)
    ([list? (car lst)]
        (+ (sumList (car lst)) (sumList (cdr lst))))
    ((not(number? (car lst)))
        (sumList (cdr lst)))
    (else 
        (+ (car lst)(sumList (cdr lst))))))
```

Comment: Short version: `(define (sumList tree) (foldl + 0 (filter number? (flatten tree))))`